# SQL field constraint that forces a column to be ascending

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, constraints

I am working on a small table that has a user input with a number field. The number that the user inputs has to be larger by a few points than the current highest number. Can I also check that the score has to be for instance 1 higher if the current highest score is < 10 but 5 higher if the current highest 10 <= score < 100?

for instance:

```
user score
1     1
1     2
1     4
1     5
1     7
```

Now, I want a constraint that will check on insert that the inserted score is bigger than the current highest score by x amount.

Is such a constraint possible?

Comment: You can't implement this in a check constraint as that can only reference the current record. You can  implement this in a trigger though, as it can reference all rows, albeit with possible performance issues. @Gordon makes a good point - if you only store the difference you could implement a check constraint that ensured it was always positive.

Answer (score 0):

Such a constraint is difficult to implement.  If you care about performance, can you simply input the difference?

```
1     1
1     1
1     2
1     1
1     2
```

If you do the data this way, then you can use `check (score > 0)` and then use `sum(score) over (order by ??)`, where `??` specifies the ordering of the rows.

Otherwise, you'll need to use either a trigger or user-defined function to implement the constraint.

Comment: I don't mind to implement a function. How would I go about using it in a check constraint?

Comment: the table consist single user data ?